# Taylor series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$ in ascending powers of $(x-2)$

Tags: analysis

I need to work out the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ in ascending powers of $(x-2)$ up to and including the term in $(x-2)^3$.

My method was to find all the derivatives (up to the third) and evaluate them at $x=0$ to give the standard geometric series formula

$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 +x +x^2 + x^3 + ...$

and replace all the $x$s with $(x-2)$. However, I don't know if this right or if I am meant to evaluate the derivatives at $x=2$ to get my coefficients...

Answer (score 3):

Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{-1}{1+(x-2)} =  -\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^n(x-2)^n.
\end{align}